# Xamarin Android- AlarmManager is taking long time to trigger

Tags: android, xamarin, alarmmanager

I need a background process to do some work at background at every hour.

I am using IntentService to set up background process and AlarmManager to schedule the background job to run at spesific interval.

**Issue**:
I have set up 10 millisecond time interval, still alarm manager is taking long time (10-15 sec) to trigger.

I am using below code for the same.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BGAgent));
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);            
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        alarm.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, 0, 10, pIntent);
```

Comment: `SetInexactRepeating` intervals are controlled by the OS, thus are prone to batching and delay in order to optimize the battery. Also a 10ms interval is not something the AlarmManager is designed for, you might use it to wake up your app every hour but then use a Handler to perform your operation at  10ms cycles until your app goes back to sleep.

Comment: thanks, 10 ms i was using for testing, in my scenario i will be using 1hr only, so is AlarmManager recommended in this case ?

Comment: Absolutely, that is a exactly what alarm manager was designed for...

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help.